# App crash when scroll on UiTableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi my App goes crash on scrolling tableview and mentain a crash log name with LowMemory.
Can anyone tell me how can i manage this. Code which i ma using is here :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSLog(@" %i",indexPath.section);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //cell=nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    UIImageView *cellBg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 90)];
    cellBg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cellbg.png"];
    [cell addSubview:cellBg];

    UILabel *lblRecipeBorder=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 5, 640, 80)];
    lblRecipeBorder.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    lblRecipeBorder.layer.borderWidth=5.0;
    lblRecipeBorder.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    lblRecipeBorder.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    [cell addSubview:lblRecipeBorder];

    UIImageView *RecipeeImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 100, 80)];
    RecipeeImg.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    RecipeeImg.layer.borderWidth=5.0;
    RecipeeImg.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    RecipeeImg.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    RecipeeImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[[appdelegate.arrFiderTool objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RecipestepPics"]];
    RecipeeImg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [cell addSubview:RecipeeImg];

    UILabel *lblRecipee=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 620, 70)];
    lblRecipee.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [lblRecipee setNumberOfLines:2];
    lblRecipee.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:52.0/255.0 blue:179.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    //lblRecipee.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    lblRecipee.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:18.0];
    //[lblMeetingId setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:14]];
    lblRecipee.text=[[appdelegate.arrFiderTool objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RecipeName"];
    [cell addSubview:lblRecipee];

    [RecipeeImg release];
    [lblRecipee release];
    [cellBg release];
    [lblRecipeBorder release];

   // }
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you should use [cell.contentView addSubview:cellBg]; for all the components first.

Comment: You are not reusing your cell correctly, every time a cell gets displayed you are adding new imageViews and labels instate of reusing the one's you have. Also variables in Objective-C should not be written with a captial.

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper i have used [cell.contentView addSubview:cellBg]; but still app crash.

Comment: what is the crash log or error you're getting in console when app crashes?

Comment: recieved memory warning and then app crashed .. no crash logs in console.

Comment: i see then you should follow "rckoenes"'s answer to manage reuse of your cell that may avoid causing of memory warning and your crash will be gone i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be reusing the labels and image views to add the cell. You can do this by subclassing the `UITableViewCell` or by giving the views tags. In my opinion subclassing is the best way, but for now I will you an example of the tagging views:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSLog(@" %i",indexPath.section);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   UIImageView *recipeImageView = nil;
   UILabel *recipeLabel = nil;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIImageView *cellBg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 90)];
        cellBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cellbg.png"];
        [cell addSubview:cellBg];

        UILabel *lblRecipeBorder=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 5, 640, 80)];
        lblRecipeBorder.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        lblRecipeBorder.layer.borderWidth=5.0;
        lblRecipeBorder.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
        lblRecipeBorder.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
        [cell addSubview:lblRecipeBorder];

        UIImageView *recipeImageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 100,    80)];
        recipeImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        recipeImageView.layer.borderWidth=5.0;
        recipeImageView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
        recipeImageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
        recipeImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        recipeImageView.tag = 456;
        [cell addSubview:recipeImageView];

        UILabel *recipeLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 620, 70)];
        recipeLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [recipeLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
        recipeLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:52.0/255.0 blue:179.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        recipeLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:18.0];
        recipeLabel.tag = 457;
        [cell recipeLabel];

        [recipeImageView release];
        [recipeLabel release];
        [cellBg release];
        [lblRecipeBorder release];
    } else {
        recipeImageView = [cell viewWithTag:456];
        recipeLabel = [cell viewWithTag:457];
    }

    NSDictionary *item = [appdelegate.arrFiderTool objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[item objectForKey:@"RecipestepPics"]];
    recipeLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"RecipeName"];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

To:

```
UITableViewCell *cell [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: not working. give    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14c1200'

Comment: How have you setup your tableView ?

Comment: This will not solve the memory issue and require you to register the `UITableViewCell` class with the `UITableView`. The problem with the code is that for every tabelview cell show in the tableview an `UIImageView` will added but it is not reused and some cell can have mutiple image vies added to them which is taking up to much memory.

Comment: To be honest the entire approach is wrong. You really want to use a custom tableViewCell and add the views to that. Then set the properties in cell:ForRowAtIndexPath. This will then ensure you re-use the UIImageViews like @rckoenes says.

Also, which version of iOS are you targeting? Why have you decided not to support ARC ?